# How to sort list of cyrilic letters in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, localization

I have list of cyrilic letters and I want to sort list alphabetically.

```
List<String> lst = ['Oбувь', 'Автомобильные запчасти'];
```

when I use codeUnitAt with 'A' it returns 1040, but with 'O' returs 79. How can I solve it?
I think that I can create custom Map for cyrilic alphabet, but at first I want to find other solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The O in your string is not a cyrrilic O but a latin O. Try copying the following character to get a cyrillic O:

```
О
```

Comment: Yeah... It seems to me that before asking such questions it is necessary to familiarize yourself with ASCII https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII. At least out of respect for those who developed it more than 50 years ago. => but with 'O' returs 79

Answer (score 1):

I faced this type of situation a lot. That's why i have a solution about it on my blog. Take a look through this link https://telegra.ph/Flutterda-Kirill-Lotin-Translator-06-03.

Also on github https://gist.github.com/jafar260698/b1b0c9963521dbff8a1606393f2ca7f2
I hope you may find it helpful.